# Passing Argument in bash

Tags: bash, arguments

I am having trouble to find the syntax error in the following script.

bash test.sh cat

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 = "cat" ]; then
echo "valid"
else
echo "invalid"
fi
```

Comment: Why do you think there's a syntax error?

Comment: I was getting  syntax error: unexpected end of file.Problem was that i needed to convert test.sh to Unix format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not giving arguments, `$1` will evaluate to a blank space and you are probably seeing `line 2: [: =: unary operator expected`.  To fix, add quotes around `$1`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "cat" ]; then
echo "valid"
else
echo "invalid"
fi
```

This way, if you don't call with an argument it will still compare to an empty string.

In general, you should always put quotes around your variable expansions, otherwise you may see unexpected errors if the variable is empty (as you just saw) or if the variable has a space in it.

Comment: Thx for the tip but this wasn't the actual problem..see my reply above

Comment: @user2650277 For future reference, if you are getting an error, you should add the error message to the question, otherwise you might get answers that are way off the mark (like mine).

Answer (score 0):

The arg `$1` has no value.  You could do something like this.

```
if [ -z $1 ]
then
echo "you forgot to give me an arg."
exit 1
fi
if [ $1 = "cat" ]; then
echo "valid"
else
echo "invalid"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   echo "Usage: ./script.sh <arg1>"
   exit 1
fi
```